# Is it possible to update timestamp automatically in geofire database while updating geolocation?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am new to GeoFire database. I can able to insert GeoLocation, but I need to timestamp. Also, is there any way to insert/update timestamp via rule or what ever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GeoFire stores (and allows querying) latitude and longitude associated with a key. It doesn't store anything else. Developers typically store additional information elsewhere in their database, under the same key. E.g. say you're storing the location of users:

```
locations
  uid1: "geohashOfLocation1"
  uid2: "geohashOfLocation2"
  uid3: "geohashOfLocation3"
users
  uid1: {
    name: "Saranya Subramanian",
    lastSeen: 1520260327510
  }
  uid2: {
    name: "Frank van Puffelen",
    lastSeen: 1520260356370
  }
  uid3: { ... }
```

So here you store the geo-data in `/locations` and query that. And you store the other information about users in `/users` and read from there when needed, e.g. when you get a user's `uid` back from a geoquery.

Also see:

- [Storing Extra Data Under GeoFire Nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42608281/storing-extra-data-under-geofire-nodes)
- [How to save GeoFire coordinates along with other items in Firebase database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38340949/how-to-save-geofire-coordinates-along-with-other-items-in-firebase-database)
- [Adding additional children when setting in GeoFire Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26184918/adding-additional-children-when-setting-in-geofire-firebase)

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation @Frank van Puffelen