# Change Geofire firebase structure with ionic

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, ionic2, geofire

Based on the documentation the geofire uses the following interface :

```
export interface GeoFireObj {
  '.priority': string;
  g: string;
  l: number[];
}
```

I would like to add title and picture to the interface so I can show an info window that displays the title and picture of each place.

I tried to change it but it did not work. my geofire set function is :

```
update(){
  this.geoFire.set({
    "some_keymscou", [45.777337, -73.632393],
    title: "Golf club",
    picture: this.pict
  }

  ).then(function () {
    console.log("Provided keys have been added to GeoFire");
  }, function (error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error);
  });
}
```

is it possible to change the geofire interface without affecting the real time queries

Comment: The option to store additional information *was* added to GeoFire for Android. But if you want to store additional information for each key in GeoFire for JavaScript you will have to store that in a separate branch of the JSON. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/42608281, https://stackoverflow.com/a/38341118, https://stackoverflow.com/a/27862654

Comment: Perfect, I saw the answer. thanks!